# How do I make a single image have an animation in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, animation

I'm trying to make a single image out of the many images on my html website have a spin animation. So far, when I attempt to do it, the spin animation is applied to all image on the site. Here is some of the code I have. (I have many other images on the site I am just trying to make the torqafflogo.png image spin.)

HTML:

```
<center> <img src="torqafflogo.png" width="215" height="215"> </center>
```

CSS:

```
 img {
  border-radius: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Here you can see live working demo: https://output.jsbin.com/tokohe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id` to this `img`, then replace `img` selector to your id selector with `#`.

HTML:

```
<center><img id="torqafflogo" src="torqafflogo.png" width="215" height="215"></center>
```

CSS:

```
#torqafflogo {
  border-radius: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

#torqafflogo:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Could you help us with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425846/why-my-image-hyperlink-clickable-from-a-large-margin-away-from-the-actual-image

Answer (score 0):

Add a `class` / `id` to that specific image and then add styling through CSS to image/s having that specific `class` / `id`

Eg (Using class):

HTML :

```
<center> <img class="spinImage" src="torqafflogo.png" width="215" height="215"> </center>
```

CSS :

```
img.spinImage {
  border-radius: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
img.spinImage:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Use `id`, if this is going to be the only image now and in the foreseeable future which you want these animations to apply.

If you use `class`, then whichever image is given that specific `class` will have those animations.

Personally, I would prefer using `class` as then the functionality can easily be extended to more such images whenever needed.

Comment: It uses `id` . Class might be better, as explained

Comment: Could you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425846/why-my-image-hyperlink-clickable-from-a-large-margin-away-from-the-actual-image

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS : 
body {
  background: #24aecd;
}

.monster {
  width: 190px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url('https://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/CSS-DD/codepen/blog/monster.png') left center;
  animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: -1900px; }
}

HTML : 
<div class="monster"></div>

Check wokring example here  :https://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/yldGp
```