How do I add a wiggle animation on layered images?
How do I add a wiggle animation on load to multiple images 
The timeline attached will load 2 images and each have a little wiggle on load.

You can do it with css keyframe animation on transform or using gsap or other js library.

As snuffy said you can do it purely by css or if you are using a builder like wp-bakery you have the ability to modify the images , you can add animation to images using the backend editor.

Could you maybe add an example of the CSS that can be used to achieve this, with some details about how it works?

I can redirect you to another question here so you can get a better hang of things
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45424177
Essentially when using css to add animation to an element , you manipulate it with transform , based on what you want to do , like slide in from left , slide in from right , rotate , and you also have to manage how the animation gets activated eg. Hover , time based , scroll based etc. You can start with hover as its easier and its css only .

I appreciate the link to an alternative answer. I already know how this works and came across your answer via the first answer review queue. My comment was to help make the answer more helpful to others rather than me asking for help myself. Including some of your comment (and an example) would improve the answer a lot :)
